# jQuery appendTo Parent Trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendto

First and foremost, thanks for the help in advance.

I am trying to basically lay a hovering `div` overtop of every anchor tag I find on a page.  So i get the offset, find the height and width of each element and then create a new div and set the CSS to those measurements.  I'm having trouble with the code that appends the newly created DIV to the parent of the anchor tag.

```
$( "a" ).each(function( index ) {
    tempoffset = $( this ).offset();
    tempheight = $( this ).height();
    tempwidth = $( this ).width();
    tempoverlay = document.createElement('div');
    tempoverlay.appendTo($(this).parent());
    tempoverlay.setAttribute("style","background: #ccc; position: fixed; height: " + tempheight + "px; width: " + tempwidth + "px; left: " + tempoffset.left + "px; top: " + tempoffset.top + "px;");
});
```

I am getting error that says

> tempoverlay.appendTo is not a function
>   Any thoughts on what may be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tempoverlay` is a native DOM node, not a jQuery object, as that's what `document.createElement` creates, and as such it has no `appendTo` method.

Create jQuery objects instead

```
var tempoverlay = $('<div />');

tempoverlay.appendTo( $(this).parent() )
           .css({
                   background : '#ccc',
                   position   : 'fixed',
                   height     : tempheigh,
                   width      : tempwidth,
                   left       : tempoffset.left,
                   top        : tempoffset.top
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `append()` instead since `tempoverlay` is not a jquery object and you can't call jquery function `.appendTo` on dom node:

```
$( "a" ).each(function( index ) {
     tempoffset = $( this ).offset();
     tempheight = $( this ).height();
     tempwidth = $( this ).width();
     tempoverlay = document.createElement('div');
     tempoverlay.setAttribute("style","background: #ccc; position: fixed; height: " + tempheight + "px; width: " + tempwidth + "px; left: " + tempoffset.left + "px; top: " + tempoffset.top + "px;");

     $(this).parent().append(tempoverlay);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`tempoverlay` is not a jQuery element. it's a dom element.

Try this: `$(tempoverlay).appendTo...`